# 'vue create xxx' - nothing happens

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have installed the latest Vue CLI, with `npm install -g @vue/cli@next`, having uninstalled the previous 'vue-cli'. Now when I try and create a Vue application with e.g. `vue create vue3-todo`, nothing happens. The command quickly executes without error (but without any prompts), and nothing is created - the directory remains empty.

Clearly something is not right with my Vue CLI installation. Any suggestions as to what the issue might be and how I can clean things up?

Comment: try to check the node and npm versions

Comment: npm install -g @vue/cli --> is the new one. I dont think you need to add @next. If it doesnt work look at your node and npm versions as Brahim says.

Comment: `node --version` gives v12.16.1, `npm --version` gives v6.13.7. I tried with just `npm install -g @vue/cli` and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with running this to uninstall:

```
npm uninstall -g vue-cli
```

Then check my node version. It's recommended to use [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) v10+ for the latest CLI.

I'd probably do a system restart just because and then reinstall:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Comment: Done this, no effect. What is really puzzling is that there does not in fact appear to be a 'create' command. This is what happens when I simply call `vue`:
```c:\Shared\playground>vue

  Usage: vue <command> [options]


  Commands:

    init        generate a new project from a template
    list        list available official templates
    build       prototype a new project
    help [cmd]  display help for [cmd]

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -V, --version  output the version number

```

Comment: What happens when you type `vue` in the terminal?

Comment: That is what is the previous comment shows (there were formatting issues). It looks to me as if the previous version is still active. I haven't actually restarted my computer yet, as I was hoping to avoid this step if possible (I have a whole bunch of applications open). Is there some way of avoiding this while ensuring everything is refreshed/

Answer (score 0):

I have got to the bottom of this. This is under Windows 10, and I noticed there was a an entry of 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' in the PATH environment variable (under 'System variables'). I looked in that directory, and sure enough, there were a bunch of 'vue*' files. I deleted these and now when I call 'vue' I get the current version as I should. Clearly these were taking precedence over the versions in my AppData/Roamin/npm directory.

I have no idea why these files were there in the first place. I am hoping that having deleted them I do not break anything.